# How do you separate the integers and letters in a string in python?

Tags: python, string, tkinter, split

When writing `45+65` into an entry box in `tkinter` it becomes a string, so how can we separate the values in the string and solve the calculation?

```
from tkinter import *
import re 

win=Tk()
A=StringVar()
def calculation():
  global A,B
  A=E1.get()
  num = re.findall(r'[\d]+', E1.get())
  B=num[0]+num[1]
  L1.configure(B)

L1=Label(win,font=("Calibri",20,"bold"))
L1.pack()
E1=Entry(win)
E1.pack()
B1=Button(win,text="Answer",command=calculation)
B1.pack()
```

I've tried using `re` but I always end up with an error. Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you tried just `r'\d+'` and `B=int(num[0])+int(num[1])`? Also, when you configure the label, you should use `text=B`, not `B` on its own.

Comment: Example string? Expected output? What re error are you getting? Low effort question.

Comment: @Junuxx The example string is the 3rd word in the question: `45+65`

Answer (score 1):

Use `split()`.

```
nums = E1.get().split('+')
B = int(nums[0]) + int(nums[1])
```

You could use a regular expression to allow other operators. Use `re.split()` to make it the delimiter. Putting it in a capture group makes the result include the delimiter.

```
num1, op, num2 = E1.get().split(r'([-+/*])')
num1 = int(num1)
num2 = int(num2)
if op == '+':
    B = num1 + num2
elif op == '-':
    B = num1 - num2
elif op == '/':
    B = num1 / num2
elif op == '*':
    B = num1 * num2
```

Answer (score 1):

Easier way to do re-wrote @Barmar.

Add `add()` function.

Snippet:

```
import tkinter as tk
 

win = tk.Tk()

def add(x, y):
   return x + y

def calculation():
  nums = E1.get().split('+')
  result = add(int(nums[0]), int(nums[1])) 
  L1.configure(text=result)

L1 = tk.Label(win,font=("Calibri",20,"bold"))
L1.pack()
E1 = tk.Entry(win)
E1.pack()
B1 = tk.Button(win,text="Answer",command=calculation)
B1.pack()

win.mainloop()
```

Screenshot:

[image]